# Select and process all attributes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I receive XML from the external system that uses attributes to communicate the values. Here is a fragment:

```
<declaratieUnica  luna_r="01" nume_declar="aaa" prenume_declar="bbb">
    <employer cif="1111" caen="0116">
</declaratieUnica>
```

In order to process this input I have to convert each attribute into a real tag with value, for example, the fragment above should become:

```
<declaratieUnica>
    <luna_r>01</luna_r> 
    <nume_declar>aaa</nume_declar>
    <prenume_declar>bbb</prenume_declar>
    <employer>
        <cif>1111</cif> 
        <caen>0116</caen>
</declaratieUnica>
```

I don't know in advance neither number of attributes, nor their names.
Is there a generic way to say in XSLT: "transform all attributes into tags with values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following stylesheet as a starter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is a simple recursive copy of the input document.
The second template matches all attribute nodes and turns them into elements.